# Calling php code from Javascript - AJAX responds with entire page's html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am still quite new to php. I have read that if you want to call a php method from a button, you will first need to assign the button's `onclick` event to call a javascript function, which in turn has to post to the php page via ajax.

Currently, my javascript is as follows:

```
 function handle_qa_submit_comment(postId, parentPostId, elem){
    //console.log(elem);
    var ajaxUrl = './index.php';
    var elem = encodeURIComponent(elem);
    var data = { 
                    action : 'add_comment',
                    data :
                    {
                        'postId' : postId,
                        'parentPostId' : parentPostId,
                        'elem' : elem
                    }
                };

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: true, 
    }).always(function(jqxhr,textStatus){
            console.log("jqxhr:");
            console.log(jqxhr);
            console.log("status:");
            console.log(textStatus);
    });
    return false;
}
```

*yes, I suspect the elem parameter is wrong - the argument supplied for that parameter is `this` on the button's `onclick` handler*

What happens in this code is that the `data` variable - as json - is being posted to my php page - index.php. my php is as follows:

```
    require 'asdf-include/app/csrf.class.php';
    require 'asdf-include/app/csrf_handler.php';

    session_start();
    $GLOBALS['csrf'] = new csrf();
    $GLOBALS['token_id'] = $csrf->get_token_id();
    $GLOBALS['token_value'] = $csrf->get_token($token_id);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $aResult = array();
    $post = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'action');

    if( !isset($post))
    { 
        //  Set base path here so this works with symbolic links for multiple installations  
        define('ASDF_BASE_DIR', dirname(empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ? __FILE__ : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/');
        require 'asdf-include/asdf-index.php';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "'data found1234'" ; // I Never saw it even get to this point
    }
```

First things first - PHP is still brand new and shiny to me. I am not sure how I will inspect the value of the `$_POST` superglobal. What matters is that it seems that the response I get from the php is the entire page's parsed html instead of what I echoed.

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way - but the goal here is that I want to call a php function from ajax. In my example here, I haven't converted the JSON properly - but that aside,

1. How do I access the contents of the post superglobal
2. Why is my response the parsed html page?

   ```
           <!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
           <!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
           <!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
           <!--[if gt IE 8]><html class="no-js"><![endif]-->

               <head>
                   <meta charset="utf-8">
                   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" >
   ```

   ...

Comment: I forgot to note. The php has the opening tag - but not the closing tag, as to avoid accidental output.

Comment: I notice you don't have type: post in the object passed to .ajax(), so you're making a GET request to index.php.

Comment: That's true, forgot that. I have however tried `$.post()` too, which gave me the same result. I removed the `$.post()` and replaced it with `$.ajax()` - Added `type: 'POST'` but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of my problems. The PHP version on our servers are 5.4.

Here is my inspection and "fixes" which I brought - which included the use of a deprecated Super Global.

Firstly - I routed the ajax url to an "empty" php page. I echoed a simple string - and found that it was exactly that which the `jqxhr` printed in the console - meaning, I will ALWAYS get the `html` of the page in the `jqxhr`.

Secondly - I used `print_r($GLOBALS);` . **Nothing was stored in `$POST`** - it printed `array ()`. However, the superglobal `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` contained the json data I sent from the ajax. Interesting.

I converted the json from the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` to an object to work with:

```
$params = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
print_r($params);

$action = $params->action;
$postId = $params->data->postId;
$parentPostId = $params->data->parentPostId;
```

--

The important observations I had was that I wasn't on the latest php (and will request an upgrade on our web servers) and that my ajax content landed in a deprecated variable.

Javascript:

```
var ajaxUrl = '../test/empty.php';

    var data = { 
                    action : 'add_comment',
                    data :
                    {
                        'postId' : postId,
                        'parentPostId' : parentPostId,
                        'elem' : $(elem).html()
                    }
                };

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: true, 
            type: 'POST'
        }).always(function(jqxhr,textStatus){
                console.log("jqxhr:");
                console.log(jqxhr);
                console.log("status:");
                console.log(textStatus);
        }).error(function(){
            //TODO uncomment when finished
            //submit_logout('/Account/Logoff');
        });
```

PHP:

```
print_r($GLOBALS); 

// This has been deprecated in PHP 5.6.0 - We currently use 5.4
$params = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
print_r($params);

$action = $params->action;
$postId = $params->data->postId;
$parentPostId = $params->data->parentPostId;
$elem = $params->data->elem;
```

OUTPUT IN CONSOLE:

```
Array
(
    **[HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA] => {"action":"add_comment","data":{"postId":5,"parentPostId":6,"elem":""}}**
    [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    [_POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
            [SUPERSECRETSTUFF] => NOPE!
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
        )

    [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
)
stdClass Object
(
    [action] => add_comment
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [postId] => 5
            [parentPostId] => 6
            [elem] => 
        )

)

empty.js:32 status:
empty.js:33 success
```